# how to programatically reassign keys in OSX?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, key-bindings

Is there an easy way to remap one keystroke to another in OSX El Capitan?

I want to assign <kbd>F13</kbd> to <kbd>⇧⌥⌘4</kbd>. (I use a little app called Imgup and that's the keystroke to upload a screenshot.)

[This answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/138609/is-there-any-way-to-programatically-remap-the-keys-in-a-macbook-running-osx-mave) suggests using Keyboard Maestro. But I'm already running Karabiner and USB Overdrive so I'm hesitant to install more software.

I'm looking through the options in Karabiner and I don't see how to simply remap one key press to another, and obviously "upload screenshot to Imgur" isn't one of the choices since it's not a system command. Also I can't use "App Shortcuts" since in Imgup there's no menu item for this action.

Is there a simple format for writing an XML snippet in Karabiner that would allow this? Something like this?

```
<item>
<name>F13 to ⇧⌥⌘4</name>
<key><f13>
<definition>4 with Command AND Option and Shift down</definition>
</item>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I'm late to the party, but here's how to do it:

1. Open Automator
2. Create a new document of the type **Service**
3. At the top of the right pane, change "Service receives selected **[ text ]**" to "Service receives **[ no input ]**" in **[ any application ]**
4. In the left pane, locate **Run AppleScript** and drag it over to the empty area in the right pane
5. Delete everything already in the AppleScript box, then copy and paste this in:

   ```
   on run {input, parameters}

       tell application "System Events"
           key code 21 using {command down, option down, shift down}
       end tell

       return input
   end run
   ```
6. Run the Service using the **Play** button in the top right of the window to make sure it does what you want.
7. **Save** the Service using whatever title you'd like. This will make it available system-wide.

   Now it's shortcut time.
8. Open System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts, and select **Services** in the left pane
9. Scroll down to the bottom to find your newly-created Service entry and add a shortcut by selecting the word *none* to the right of it. In your case, this is where you'd press the <kbd>F13</kbd> key on your keyboard.
10. Switch focus to any other app (Finder, for example) and give the new shortcut a shot.
11. Profit

Answer (score 0):

[Karabiner-Elements](https://Karabiner-Elements.pqrs.org) 11.6.0 maps <kbd>F13</kbd> to <kbd>⇧⌥⌘4</kbd> in MacOSX 10.11 El Capitan and later with

```
{"title": "Imgup F13 to ⇧⌥⌘4",
 "rules": [
   {"description": "Imgup F13 to ⇧⌥⌘4.",
    "manipulators": [
      {"type": "basic",
       "from": {"key_code": "f13"},
       "to": [{"key_code": "4", "modifiers": ["shift", "option", "command"]}]}]}]}
```

in a file like **~/.config/karabiner/assets/complex_modifications/imgup.json** enabled by *Karabiner-Elements > Window > Karabiner-Elements Preferences > Complex Modifications > Rules > Add Rule*